Reuse the same ui objects on different tabs in shiny app
I would like to create a shiny app with tabs using a modular approach, but I would like some tab selections to show the same page/collection of uiobjects as each other. Importantly, I don't want to create the same page/module/uiobjects twice and match the state of the iuobjects between each instance. I have a reprex below which currently creates the same module twice with the same id (I think all I've achieved here is bad coding practice!). Is there a way that mod_test_ui("test_1") can be created once and displayed when either tab1_DROPDOWN or tab2_DROPDOWN is selected?
This answer gives a solution when not using modules, but it is unclear how it could be achieved using modules.
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(shinythemes)

mod_test_ui <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    fluidRow(
      h2("MODULE1"),
      
      selectInput(inputId = ns("dropdown"),
                  label = "DROPDOWN",
                  choices = c("aa","bb"),
                  selected = "aa"
      ),
      
      textOutput(ns("text"))
      
    )
  )
}


mod_test_server <- function(id, df, vbl, threshhold) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    
    output$text <- renderText({input$dropdown})
    
    
  })
}


ui <- fluidPage(

  navbarPage("",
             
             navbarMenu('menu 1',
                        tabPanel("tab1_DROPDOWN",
                                 fluidRow(
                                   mod_test_ui("test_1")
                                 )
                        ),
                        tabPanel("tab2",
                                 fluidRow(
                                   h2("things and stuff")
                                 )
                        )
                        
                        
             ),
             navbarMenu('menu 2',
                        tabPanel("tab1",
                                 fluidRow(
                                   h2("Blah blah")
                                 )
                        ),
                        tabPanel("tab2_DROPDOWN",
                                 fluidRow(
                                   h2("Box Plot"),
                                   mod_test_ui("test_1")
                                 )
                        )
                        
             )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  mod_test_server("test_1")
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)


Reusing the same ui objects (same ID) contradicts shiny's module approach, which is based on creating separate namespaces for different module instances (resulting in unique IDs). The same was discussed here.
